# Refresh Button when clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

I got a button which i want to reload on click. But only the button should be reloaded, not the rest of the page.

The button looks like this:

```
<a href="{$module_data.GM_PRODUCTS_BUTTON_BUY_NOW_URL}" id="click{php}echo ''.$counter.'';{/php}" class="addcart button_green button_set action_add_to_cart"{if $module_data.PRODUCTS_NAME != ''} title="{$module_data.PRODUCTS_NAME|replace:'"':'&quot;'} {$txt.text_buy}"{/if}
onclick="return checkAddToCart(event, '{$module_data.QTY_DATA.ID}', {$product_stock}, {$product_max_order}, {$module_data.PRODUCTS_ID}, {php}echo $row['customers_basket_quantity']{/php}, {php}echo "'click".$counter."'";{/php});">
    <span class="button-outer">
        <span class="button-inner">{$button.add_to_cart}</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Now i told javascript that `echo "'click".$counter."'";` is the clickid.
I tried the following thing to reload my page on click:

```
function checkAddToCart(event, tid, stock, maxallowed, pid, pquantity, clickid)
{
    var clickid_string = clickid.toString();
    var bought = Number($("#"+tid).val());
    stock = Number(stock);
    maxallowed = Number(maxallowed);
    var ans = (bought>stock) || (bought > maxallowed);

    if(ans) 
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Maximale Bestellmenge:  " + Math.min(maxallowed, stock));
    }
    else {
        $("#"+clickid_string).load("#"+clickid_string);
    }

    return !ans;
}
```

It is not working, and i have absolutly no idea why. By the ay, my system works with SMARTY tpl.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? What is the output of `console.log(event, tid, stock, maxallowed, pid, pquantity, clickid)` as the first like in `checkAddToCart`? Is that function even being fired?

Comment: the output is:

(event, 'gm_attr_calc_qty_38', 883, 8, 38, , 'click1')

The number before the "click1" only appears if you already clicked the button once. Thats why i want to reload it on click. On Every click this number (the quantity of how much you got in your cart) has to be updated there.

No errors in console but instead of reloading it shows me a page with a strange little icon moving around. That's weird.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a php script on click of a button you need to learn ajax. Ajax its just a simple way to use javascript, to run pages in background without reload the current page.

```
<span class="button-outer" onClick="addDataToDB(this);">...</span>
<script>
function addDataToDB(el) {
   var elem = $(el);
   /* GET ALL YOUR DATA*/
   var name = ...

   /* Create an AJAX request to your phpfunction */
}
</script>
```

Check some tutorials in youtube.